# Add x Days to a Date Based on vlookup Output Excel

Tags: excel, date, vlookup

What I'm trying to do is give a due date based on an input date, type of review, and department.

For example if the department is `ABC` and the review is `retrospective`, the due date will be the `input date + 30 days`.

But if the department is `ABC` and the review is `concurrent`, then the due date will be `input date + 1 day`.

I know I can concatenate the department and review into the vlookup table but I'm not so sure how to get the output to be the due date that I want.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Per the first answer below, I hashed out an input table with concatenated columns just in case I needed them. It is a bit more complicated than I originally thought.

[Input table with date logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8suMY.png)

I'd love to simply edit the source data but the report isn't readily available in the database. Could I still use the suggestions below?

Comment: Use a lookup table for the `x` days as well - but we really need some sample data and the expected output to answer the question satisfactorily.

Comment: I don't really know how to add data in here but I will try to be more descriptive. I have a spreadsheet where data from a canned report gets pasted into and I need to calculate a due date based on three columns: Department, Input date, and review type. The goal is to get the output to have a due date column with the input date+ the appropriate number of days. I have a table that combines department and type so I have something like 'ABC-Retrospective' going into the vlookup.

Comment: My understanding of your comment would be to do another lookup with a sort of inbetween output. So if my 'ABC-Retrospective' were to spit out a value like +30, I could have a vlookup table relating +30 to "column of interest+30"? How do I reference the correct column? Let me know if this is sufficient information.

Comment: Maybe instead of vlookup you could use SUMIFS. Consider adding a screenshot or at least some sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a lookup table for the number of days to add depending upon the department and review type similar to the one below, you can use an `INDEX`/`MATCH`/`MATCH` and simply add it to the input date:

```
=$A2+INDEX($H$4:$J$5,MATCH($B2,$G$4:$G$5,0),MATCH($C2,$H$3:$J$3,0))
```

[image]

**SOLUTION FOR AN ALTERNATIVE LOOKUP TABLE LAYOUT**

If your layout table is more like as below, you can use a `MINIFS` formula (or `MAXIFS` if you would prefer):

```
=$A2+MINIFS($I$3:$I$8,$G$3:$G$8,$B2,$H$3:$H$8,$C2)
```

[image]